# Why does Google's app-passwords always say the password is wrong?

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, gmail-imap, authorization

After I have enabled the two-step-authorization, I cannot login my Gmail via Thunderbird anymore!

I then noticed there is a way to do so with app passwords.

So, I tried it, but it didn't work.

Thunderbird threw a "The Username or Password is invalid" error.

[image: Screenshoot]

And in the app password control page, it says that the password has never been used! (The last-used field is `-`)

[image: Screenshot]

So, what can I do to make Thunderbird work?

Should I cancel the two-step-authorization?

Comment: Thunderbird has native OAuth support for Gmail, doesn't it?

Comment: @grawity Yes, it has. And the authorization method is OAuth2

Comment: Well it shouldn't even _ask_ for a password then, it should just pop up Gmail's login page...

Comment: @grawity but it not, look at my second screenshoot

Comment: I can't read those screenshots, but what you describe is exactly how it should work - generate an app password and copy/paste it into your app's authentication. Just don't use your actual password in the app anywhere and it *should* work.

Comment: Firstly, Update Thunderbird to the latest version.

Comment: @Raystafarian The screenshot says that the "Username or Password Invalid" I haven't use the actual password outside thunderbird, and it still not work. I now guess that if network condition not very well, will it show "Username or Password Invalid" message? In China mainland, people cannot connect to any google devices directly, we must use proxy servers. So, maybe the terrible network is to blame. Nevertheless, Google's webmail is available via a proxy.

Comment: @Private I firstly tried Thunderbied from Arch Package Mirror, it wasn't work. I then downloaded it from its official website, it did not work again.

Comment: @Raystafarian I have made these screenshot into English. You can see it now.

Comment: Ah, proxies. I'm sure that has something to do with it, but not my specialty. Good luck!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally copy extra characters?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem but eventually found the answer: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?ul=en&hl=en
It's about "Some Desktop mail clients like Microsoft Outlook and Mozilla Thunderbird".